# How to easily diff configuration properties that live in different branches

Tags: git, spring-cloud-config

I'm currently in a Java with microservices environment, and we are using Spring Cloud resources, and particularly Spring Cloud Config.

The situation is that in that Cloud Config service we have several configuration files for each microservice like: `service1.yml`, `service2.yml`, etc.

For each environment we have these `.yml` files defined in a different branch with it's corresponding values, i.e.: `dev` branch will have `service1.yml` file populated with the properties for dev environment, `test` branch will have `service1.yml` file populated with the properties for test environment, and so on...

The main issue with this approach is that when merging changes from one environment to another (dev -> test for example), the diff between these two branches is too big and requires a lot of time to review all the changes maded. And another problem is that it's easy when reviewing that diff to make a mistake and skip a change made that is not a new property (easy to see with a graphical diff tool), but a change to an existing property which is really difficult to distinguish if it's an actual change made in one of the branches, or just a different value inherent to the environment.

Is there a Git feature that i'm not seeing that allows me to take like a snapshot of the source branch and make the diff's vs that snapshot?
I already know that this is possible making an apply of the range of commits made in the source branch to the destination branch, but I really need this behavior when doing a merge.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a Git feature that i'm not seeing that allows me to take like a snapshot of the source branch ...

Commits *are* snapshots, and branch names are just a method of finding commits.  So Git is already doing that.

> and make the diff's vs that snapshot?

This is what `git diff` does.  Given:

```
git diff <left-side-commit-specifier> <right-side-commit-specifier>
```

Git extracts the left and right side commits (in memory) and diffs them.  The two specifiers here can be anything acceptable via [the gitrevisions syntax](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions), including two branch names.

If you'd like to limit the output of `git diff`, there are many options for this.  The one that seems most applicable here is that you can tell `git diff` to show only those paths that meet some path specification.  The full details for *pathspecs* are found in [the gitglossary](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary) (which is a somewhat odd place for them) but the simplest pathspec is just a file name, complete with slashes:

```
git diff br1 br2 -- config/service1.yml
```

for instance.  The `--` here is to make sure that the pathspec doesn't accidentally match something else—for instance, if the file of interest is named `-s`, that looks like the `-s` or `--no-patch` option, and `git diff br1 br2 -s` would therefore suppress the actual diff, so if you need to name the *file* `-s` you can use `git diff br1 br2 -- -s`.

It's not a bad habit to get into, to just use the `--` everywhere, in case you ever find yourself with a *file* named `master` for instance.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation, I didn't know that about the --. I still can't see a way to get through this.
For example: I have service1.yml on dev branch with props: prop1: url_dev and prop2: alice; on the other branch test I also have service1.yml with props: prop1: url_test and prop3: bob. The question is: is there a way that when I compare the two branches dev and test, the output excludes the diff on prop1?
I think the answer is no, because when comparing the two branches there will be a commit that sets the prop1 so it will be included on diff. You see a way to get through it? Thx

Comment: @tbotalla: Separate the problem into component parts: (1) extract a commit. You can do this with `git checkout`, which extracts a commit into your work-tree, or with `git archive` to make a commit into an archive (tarball or zip file) that you can extract with `tar` or `unzip`.

Comment: (2) Use the extracted commit however you like. You can diff it straight up, or remove particular files whose differences you don't care about, after which any diff program won't say anything about those files because they're *not in the snapshot any more*. If the files have individual *lines* that might differ, and you want to ignore those differences, delete or replace those *lines*. They're just files out of a snapshot now. You can do anything you like *to* them.

Comment: If you're doing this work within a work-tree, you have to be careful, because you might also be trying to do ordinary work (rather than this limited diff-ing) in this work-tree. So it's probably better to copy the snapshots elsewhere first. But just think about it in these terms: Git stores *commits*, which are snapshots frozen in time forever. You don't do anything *to* a commit, you just extract it. After you extract it, you have *files*, and they're *yours!* You can do anything you like with them. If they are in your work-tree, you can `git add` and `git commit` them to make a *new* commit.

Comment: Note that when you use `git diff` on a *commit*, it just extracts that commit (to memory rather than to files). You can apply `git diff` to two trees (folders-full-of-files), even if they are outside your work-tree area, though. See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/61902662/1256452

Answer (score 0):

Use command

```
git diff dev test -- service1.yml
git diff dev test -- path\foo\bar\service1.yml
```

Trick: If you use GitHub or GitLab web GUI, You can create a (fake/dummy) merge request, in merge request GUI, you can press button compare, very easy to view differents.

[image]