# Check for new files only (not modified) in different branches in git

Tags: git

I have the following folder structure in

1. branch1

```
    -releases
       -dev
          file1.txt
          file2.text
```

2. branch2

```
    -releases
       -stg
          file1.txt
          file3.text
```

Now, I want to know only the file which is not present in branch2. In this case `file2.txt`. Even if `file1.txt` is different, I don't want it to be displayed.

I tried something like

```
git diff  --name-only branch1:releases/dev  branch2:releases/stg
```

This displays all the files that are changed i.e. it also displays `file1.txt`
How can I get the desired result?

Answer (score 1):

Files are neither in, nor not-in, *branches*.  Files, in Git, are stored in *commits*.  That is, each commit has a complete snapshot of all of its files—so two different commits can have two different sets of files in them.

*Branch names* simply serve to identify commits.  So branch names `branch1` and `branch2` each identify some commit.  The *real* name of a commit is its hash ID, but hash IDs are impossible for humans to work with, so Git gives us other ways to name commits.

To compare any two commits, you can use `git diff` as you were trying to do:

```
git diff <left-side-commit-specifier> <right-side-commit-specifier>
```

—but this doesn't get you want you want, even though the two commit specifiers can just be branch names:

```
git diff branch1 branch2
```

In particular, you *can't* do a partial comparison of `releases/dev/*` in the commit named by `branch1` vs `releases/stg/*` in the commit named by `branch2`.  Git will compare the *entire snapshots*, and since `releases/dev/` is different from `releases/stg/`, these are quite likely to name different files.<sup>1</sup>

What this means is that you will have to extract both commits, or at least, the interesting parts of both commits.  You can then use any diff program—`git diff` included, if you prefer it—to compare these *extracted* sub-trees.  For instance:

```
# first, make two directories to compare the trees
mkdir /tmp/left /tmp/right

# now extract releases/dev/ from branch1's tip commit, into /tmp/left
git archive --format=tar branch1 -- releases/dev |
    tar -C /tmp/left --strip-components=2 xf -

# and extract releases/stg/ from branch2's tip commit
git archive --format=tar branch1 -- releases/stg |
    tar -C /tmp/right --strip-components=2 xf -
```

At this point you can `git diff /tmp/left /tmp/right`.  You can add `--name-only` if you like, or `--name-status` to get status letters, and you can add `--diff-filter=A` to discard any listing whose status would not be `A` (added, new file).

Remember to clean up (remove the temporary left and right side of diff directories) when you're done.  For production use, change the hardcoded names `/tmp/left` and `/tmp/right` to use `mktemp -d`.

---

<sup>1</sup>This gets us into a side discussion.  Since each commit is a standalone snapshot of *all* of its files, what does it mean to claim that `releases/dev/file1.txt` in the left side commit is "the same file" as `releases/stg/file1.txt` in the right side commit?  These are obviously totally different files, because they have different *names*.  But maybe they are the same file, because maybe they have the same, or very similar, *content*.

When you use `git diff` on two *commits*, Git considers the commits as a whole.  The left side commit has files, and each of those files has a name, such as `releases/dev/file1.txt`.  The right side commit has files, and each of those files has a name too.  Maybe the *files* are the same even if the *names* have changed.  Or maybe they aren't the same, because the names have changed.

Git offers you an option here:

- You can decree that if the names are different, the files are *definitely* different.  To do this, simply make sure that Git's *rename detection* is turned off.
- Or, you can decree that if the left side commit has a file whose name doesn't appear at all in the right side commit, and the right side has some file whose name doesn't appear in the left side commit, Git should try to *detect* whether the file has been renamed.  To do this, make sure that Git's *rename detection* is turned on, and set a *similarity index* value.  This similarity index is Git's way of deciding that file `left/side/name.ext`, which is obviously not the same as `right/newname.newext`, could be the same anyway.  If the *contents* of those two differently-named files match, to some degree of similarity, Git will declare that those are "the same file" after all.

  The default similarity threshold is set to 50%, but you can choose any other value you like.  Git does not document how it computes its similarity index so anything you put in here is going to be guesswork anyway, but in general, the more the two files match up, the higher the similarity index will be.